# Finding the smallest integer in an array using a recursive function (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, function, recursion

I have to write a function that uses recursion in order to determine the smallest number in an array. But I have no idea how to approach this, since recursion is not really a part of the introductory course I am taking, but they want to give us some exposure to it.

So far I've had the following idea (but it does not rely on recursion, and I have not made it go through the entire array):

```
           if numbers[0] <= numbers[1]:
                 del numbers[1]
           else:
                 del numbers[0]
```

Where numbers is an array, for instance numbers=[2,1,3,4]. For that instance I would want the function to return 1 as the smallest integer in the array. But how do I go about using a recursive function to solve this?

PS: We use Python 3.

Comment: Try using the following fact: minimum of `array` is minimum of two numbers: `array[0]` and minimum of the rest of array (i.e. `array[1:]`).

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35282042/find-the-second-smallest-number-in-a-list-using-recursion?rq=1. If that does not help I could provide an outline for the solution( since this is homework)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a builtin function (min), but if you really want to iterate, you can also use a for cicle. The variable "i" goes through the array and gets each value in the iteration. You can also use while cicles to iterate but is not recommended in this case

```
numbers=[2,1,3,4]

#using min builtin function
print(min(numbers))     

#using for
low_num = numbers[0]
for i in numbers:
    if i < low_num:
        low_num = i
print(low_num)
```

Comment: Where is the recursion?

Comment: + it will always return either `arr[0]` or `1`.

Comment: @ImanolLuengo you're right, i mispelled i with 1. Fixed, thanks for the observation